# Actual and formal argument lists differ in length 1 error

Tags: java

Actual and formal argument lists differ in length 1 error and cannot figure out this problem. What is going wrong? I want to get 3 numbers from a user, and then organize them in a order from smallest to biggest number.Can someone please explain to me? I have one error code:

```
(ThreeNumbers.java:14: error: constructor ThreeNumbers in class ThreeNumbers cannot be applied to given types;

    ThreeNumbers X = new ThreeNumbers(n1, n2, n3);
                   ^
  
required: no arguments
  found: int,int,int
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error
)
```

Here is the code:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    
    public class ThreeNumbers 
    { 
    
    Scanner Y = new Scanner(System.in);
     
     int n1 = Y.nextInt();
    
     int n2 = Y.nextInt();
    
     int n3 = Y.nextInt();
     
    
    public int main(String [] args)
     {
      
    ThreeNumbers X = new ThreeNumbers(n1, n2, n3);
    
        if (n1 > n2) {
        return n1;
        return n2;
        }
        else {
        return n2;
        return n1;
            };
        
         if (n2 > n3) {
        return n2;
        return n3;
        }
        else {
        return n3;
        return n2;
        };
        
         if (n1 > n3) {
        return n1;
        return n3;
        } 
        else {
        return n3;
        return n1;
        };
    
          System.out.println (X);
    };
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

The class `ThreeNumbers` does not define a constructor with 3 int arguments. Just the implicit constructor without arguments is there. So you could create a new instance with `new ThreeNumbers()` but not with `new ThreeNumbers(n1, n2, n3)`.

Also, why do you need to create an instance of this class at all? And btw the main method should be declared with `public static void main(String [] args)`

For a few more problems in the code see also the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have not defined any constructors so only the default non-args constructor will be available.

Also

```
Scanner Y = new Scanner(System.in);
int n1 = Y.nextInt();
int n2 = Y.nextInt();
int n3 = Y.nextInt();
```

needs to be in a code-block, try moving it to your `main` method.

Note, when this code is in your `main` method, you will notice that you do not even need any other constructor.

**edit**

There should not be semi-colons after your ending curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the problem mentioned by other users , there is one more issue

```
  if (n1 > n2) {
        return n1;
        return n2;
        }
```

After `return n1` , next statement is unreachable and you should get compile time issue. Not sure you are using any compiler or Command line.